# Python - How to extract numbers in list A depending on list B?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

My purpose is:
For every element in B, I want to create a list, in which it contains elements of list B and smaller elements(than B element) in list A.

I tried two for loops, however, I do not know how to finish this work :

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
B=[3,4,5]
C=[]
for i in B:
    for r in A:
        if i>=r:
            C.append(r)
```

I expect a result like this:

```
[[3,1,2,3],[4,1,2,3,4],[5,1,2,3,4,5]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Rephrased title and edited the body to suit expectations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in B:
    new_list = [i]  # inner list starting with the elmt from B
    for r in A:
        if i >= r:
            new_list.append(r)  # append to inner list
    C.append(new_list)  # finally append inner list to C
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an array inside one of the loops:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
B=[3,4,5]
C=[]
for b in B:
    c = [b]
    for a in A:
        if a <= b:
            c.append(a)
    C.append(c)
print(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to write this in one line:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
B=[3,4,5]
C=[[b] + [a for a in A if a <= b] for b in B]
print(C)
```

prints

```
[[3, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be following :

```
try:
    A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    B = [3, 4, 5]
    D = []
    a = sorted(A)
    for b in B:
        temp = [b]
        temp.extend(a[0: a.index(b) + 1])
        D.append(temp)
    print(D)
except ValueError as e:
    pass  # Do something when value in B not found in a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter and list comprehension for one line operation

```
print [[i]+filter(lambda x: x <= i, A) for i in B]
```

results in

```
[[3, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
B=[3,4,5]
res=list()
for i in B:
    C=list()
    C.append(i)
    for r in range(0,i):
        C.append(A[r])
    res.append(C)
print res,
```